# Failed to setup the capture workspace for object_recognition

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am following [quick guide of recognition kitchen].(http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/ros_quickguide.html)

But when I run this code in my third terminal:

```
  rosrun object_recognition_core orb_template.py -o my_textured_plane
```

I got this message in terminal:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./orb_template.py", line 3, in <module>
      from object_recognition_capture.orb_capture import *
  ImportError: No module named object_recognition_capture.orb_capture
```

Does anybody know how to get this module(object_recognition_capture.orb_capture)?
I am using electric on Ubuntu 10.10.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

After I:

```
  sudo apt-get install ros-electric-object-recognition
```

The error message became:

```
  Listening for key: s on imshow:save
  Registration? 1
  Sync? 0
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File       "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition_core/bin/orb_template.py", line 95, in <module>
run_plasm(options, plasm, locals=vars())
    File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition_core/pyshared/ecto/opts.py", line 90, in run_plasm
sched.execute(options.niter, options.nthreads)
  ecto.CellException:            exception_type  CellException
                  cell_name  Source
                  cell_type  ecto::py::BlackBox
              function_name  process
                       type  std::runtime_error
                       what             exception_type  CellException
                  cell_name  ecto_openni::OpenNICapture
                  cell_type  ecto_openni::OpenNICapture
              function_name  configure
                       type  std::runtime_error
                       what  Index out of range.0 devices found.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42080/failed-to-setup-the-capture-workspace-for-object_recognition/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install `object_recognition` from source or as a deb package? I just tested with...

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-object-recognition
```

... and it worked (at least I got past the point where you got that error). Make sure you don't have another copy of `object_recognition` checked out somewhere on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-09-05**:
I followed your installation method and the error came different.I'll try other way.Thank you!